# Modify columns in CSV with a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have some huge csv logs (a lot of columns and rows) which I need to modify as follows:

1. Delete the first two lines
2. Delete the very last line
3. Remove some columns
4. Substitute the value of some columns with their md5sum

For point (1) and (2), I think it could be suitable this approach:

```
tail -n +3 file.csv > temp_file.csv
mv temp_file.csv file.csv
head -n -1 file.csv > temp_file.csv
mv temp_file.csv file.csv
```

For point (3) it should be (let's assuming I'm dropping columns 5 and 25):

```
cut -d , -f 1-4,6-24,26- file.csv
```

For point (4) I don't have any idea :|

Comment: extract the values of the columns, call md5sum on them, and use `sed` to substitute value by md5. Frankly it would be 1000 times simpler using python.

Comment: `awk` is likely to be the best solution. You can do all 4 steps in a single script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove some columns, you need to know what is the number column. IE, to remove the the columns between 5° and 25°:

```
cut -d, -f5-25 --complement temp.csv
```

-d, defines the delimiter ','
-f2 select the field 2
--complement complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields

To substitute the value of some columns with their md5sum, you could use an AWK and add a column with the md5 value, and late drop the column original